# How to avoid reading #Div/0 from Excel using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to read some numerical values from Excel files, while proceeding to read the numbers on a column I want to avoid the division by zero cells. I know that there are 4 or 5 among 100 numbers. 
I used the if not conditions in the way:

```
N=[]
If not ZerodivisionError:
    N.append(cell.value)

Else
    Break
```

But this turns the list empty. If I don't use the condition the error numbers will also be present in the list

Comment: What is the reason for down voting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and would like to leave it here to be more useful :

Since division by zero is as '#DIV/0!', that's enough to set the condition :

```
if  type(cell.value) is not str :
```

and the cell will be avoided

Answer (score 1):

Why not trap the error in the excel spreadsheet earlier:

```
=IFERROR(your_formula,0)
```

Replace the zero as suits your application : a blank or text etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, well this will be a question for me how to, cause this should be more feasible by xlwings than openpyxl to access the formulas. But I wanted to avoid modifying my excel files

Comment: Also, this might change so many formulas to zero, that I might not notice later

Comment: So change the zero to something you can spot - which is different to the range of your data such as 99999 or 75757575 etc

Comment: thank you, but is it because there's no other way to stop reading when the code arrives to a division by zero. Since I'm gonna use them for data mining numbers are important and I need to avoid erroneous ones

Comment: You tagged it excel, so I offered an excel based option which deals with div0 at source. If you want a solution that is applied later then that’s fine - it does not change what I offered.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also for mentioning the tag, just added python

Comment: I have written my own answer and it works quite well ! Strange that it has got negative vote,  still I have noticed that if my text is something like : 

A @ B , Python can not find it with if clause